# Change a page for other users by what a admin selects in a form in PHP

Tags: php

I am stuck with a bit of a problem.

I have to build an application that shows everyone that visits the webserver a message which says if there is maintenance or a failure on the server.

Which of the 2 messages gets shown to the user depends on what the admin sets it to. This is done by clicking one of two buttons on the admin page.

I got it working to the point where if I click one of the two buttons on the admin page it redirects me to the index page and shows the right text.

My problem is that the choice I made is a one time thing and will not be saved.
Meaning that if anyone else visits the site he/she gets to see an empty index page.

I am not allowed to use a database to store the choice i made, so I will have to store the variable somewhere else.
But I have no idea how to save a variable without a database.

My code goes something like this:

Index.php:

```
if(!session_id()) session_start();

$filename = $_SESSION['filename'];

 $page = $_POST['sb'];
 // // echo $page;
 //
 if($page == 'Maintenance')
 {
      require './pages/index.html';
 }
 elseif($page == 'Failure')
 {
      require './pages/fail.html';
 }
```

Admin.php:

```
 if(!session_id()) session_start();
 //include("global.php");
 $_SESSION['filename'] = $page;

 require './functions.php';

 $page = $_POST['sb'];
 change();
```

Functions.php:

```
   if(!session_id()) session_start();
    $filename = "test";
    if(!isset($_SESSION['filename'])) {
        $_SESSION['filename'] = $filename;
    }
         echo '<div class="switch">' .
                   '<form method="POST" action="../index.php">' .
                   '<input class="button" type="submit" name="sb" value="Maintenance">' .


          '<input class="button" type="submit" name="sb" value="Failure">' .
           '</form>' .
           '</div>';
}
```

Comment: You can just persist the state with a simple toggle in the `$_SESSION` variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a txt file as a place to store your data and retrieve it in the index file to display the correct page.

Posting "sb" to txt file on server:

```
<?php
if($_POST['sb'] != ""){
$file = fopen('sbstore.txt', 'w');
fwrite($file, $_POST['sb']);
fclose($file);
}
?>
```

Retrieving data from txt file on server:

```
<?php
if (filesize('sbstore.txt') != 0){
$txt_file = file_get_contents('sbstore.txt');
$sb = $txt_file;
} else {
$sb = "Default";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this is not working at the moment. I have placed the top code in the page where the button is clicked, but when I click a button it does not create a file. I also tried making the file myself but it does not write in this either. Do you have any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: I just tried it on my localhost on my laptop and it does work there, so I guess I will have to figure out why it does not work in the actual project. But thanks  anyways.